# Unable to add related record component (standard) in app builder record page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lightning-components

I am trying to add the related record component (standard lightning component) inside account record page. While adding there is no error. Its got activated successfully but when I am coming back to UI then the component is not visible. Again when I am going back to app builder page editor I can see that component is not available in the page.

Even I tried to add other standard lightning component but for all its same.
Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Does the user have permissions to the related object?

Comment: Hi David, Thanks! Yaa I am trying for Account object and system admin profile

Comment: What about the related object?  if you don't have permissions to the related object, then you won't see the related list will not appear.

Comment: all permission are in place. but its not showing